# Internacionalização com Labels de Enums

Tags: java, jsf, enums, i18n, internacionalização

Olá estou tentando fazer internacionalização com labels vindos de um enum:

```
public enum WeekDay {
  MONDAY("msg.week_monday", "mon"), 
  TUESDAY("msg.week_tuesday", "tue"), 
  WEDNESDAY("msg.week_wednesday", "wed"),
  THURSDAY("msg.week_thursday", "thu"), 
  FRIDAY("msg.week_friday", "fri"), 
  SATURDAY("msg.week_saturday", "sat"),
  SUNDAY("msg.week_sunday", "sun");

    private String label;
    private String value;

    private WeekDay(String label, String value) {
        this.label = label;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;

    }
}
```

e chamo na pagina assim :

```
  <f:selectItems value="#{myMB.weekDays}"
                                    var="dayWeek" itemValue="#{dayWeek}"
                                    itemLabel="#{dayWeek.label}" />
```

Porém o resultado são os literais das labels e não seu correspondente no meu arquivo msg.properties:

```
week_monday=Segunda-feira
week_tuesday=Ter\u00E7a-feira
week_wednesday=Quarta-feira
week_thursday=Quinta-feira
week_friday=Sexta-feira
week_saturday=S\u00E1bado
week_sunday=Domingo
```

Quando chamo desta forma `itemLabel="#{msg.week_monday}"` funciona, alguém sabe como fazer? estou tento o mesmo problema tentando traduzir campos vindo do banco.

Answer (score 1):

Faça assim dentro do `getLabel`

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();              
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context,  label, String.class);
```

Esse código vai fazer que o valor do bean `msg` seja processado dentro da Enum.

Comment: Vlw Renato, consegui simplesmente trocando    `itemLabel="#{msg[dayWeek.label]}`  por `itemLabel="#{msg[dayWeek.label]}"`

Comment: Digo: Vlw Renato, consegui simplesmente trocando    `itemLabel="#{dayWeek.label}`  por `itemLabel="#{msg[dayWeek.label]}"`